# How to make rainbow ends fade out

Tags: materials

I needed to add a rainbow to a scene and found the info below that I used and made an awesome rainbow with just a few tweaks. The problem is that real rainbows usually fade out on the ends, the rainbow I make is from an extruded circle, and when I delete half of the circle the end is sharp and I can't find a way to fade out the ends of the rainbow. Is it possible?

Harold

BA thread [How-to-improve-this-rainbow](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?294698-How-to-improve-this-rainbow)

[image]

Comment: the solution is their in the thread in [Kaluura post](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?294698-How-to-improve-this-rainbow&p=2390923&viewfull=1#post2390923)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I use his node set up and the inner and outer edges fade but not the ends, I have tried separating the end faces and adding another gradient and mapping node but that didnt work.

Comment: can you post your result , or even upload the file so we can work on it ?

Comment: I don't want to appear to be stupid but how do I upload my file?

Comment: no problem , see this [help page](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/)  then copy and past the link in your question

Comment: FANTASTIC!! SWEET !! AWESOME !! This is what I was looking for!  You are a genius my man a pure genius!!!

Answer (score 4):

One way to fix this is by placing the UVmap inside the texture space bounds :

[image]

then you can use the UV output directly in the ColorRamp input:

[image]

and here is the render :

[image]