# How to make a circular rainbow effect?

Tags: node-editor, effects

I've played *Nier Gestalt* and *Beyond Two Souls* games recently and noticed  that in both of them the circular/half-circular rainbow effect appears.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Could somebody tell me what is this effect called and how to achieve it in Blender? I know I can create it using transparent and color ramp nodes (like in here: [How to make rainbow ends fade out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29250/how-to-make-rainbow-ends-fade-out)), but how to make it physically acurate? This effect appears when you rotate camera out from the light source. The more you rotate from it, the more the effect appears.

Comment: Halo maybe? Get a transparent rainbow image and overlay it in the node editor?

Comment: It's lens flare effect, you can achieve it in compositor. Google it, there are some good tutorials about it, and sadly I can't do something as long right now for you.

Comment: You can't make it physically acurate, since rainbows don't appear in thin air like that. A real camera lens flare also doesn't look like that. It's a cool effect, though.

Comment: Only the first image looks like a rainbow effect or some sort of shock-wave maybe. It is impossible to make such physically correct effect in Blender, because Blender does not support light dispersion. You need to fake it. A transparent texture on plane or particles is your best bet.

The rest are lens-flares. You can learn how to make such effect in post-production here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1865/7777

Comment: @Sybren I don't know what photography background you have but this is real camera lens effect. Especially when you are using old lenses without coating.

Comment: I have quite a few old cameras (oldest one is from 1917), but I've never seen lens flare like this.

Comment: Apparently this is an effect of the human iris http://simonwinder.com/projects/simulation-of-lens-flare-in-the-human-eye/ "In addition to the rotationally symmetric point spread function, there are also radial corona rays that are generated by mutliplying by a uniform deviate in the range 0 to 1 as a function of orientation. A different set of random numbers is used for the rays of the lenticular halo."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Flare fringe]

This is a post effect as it occurs inside the lens. I have used a mask to create the ring, then added some noise from a cloud texture, this is distorted radially to make streaks (that you could animate). Then this is coloured with a fringe using the Projector node.

Make a single mask with 2 circle shapes on their own layers:

1. Layer one use Add function

[image: First mask]

2. Layer two use a Merge Subtract function

[image: Second mask]

3. Make sure both layers are active, tick the eye buttons

[image: Both mask layers]

Use this mask shape with a noise texture that is distorted with a radial blend texture using a UV map node:

[image: Radial mask nodes]

Here's the blend file I created for this effect: [image]

UPDATE:
Here's the flare turned up to 11!
I duplicated the projector node for more color and added a ramp to the radial blend so that I could better control the stretch of the cloud texture.

[image: uber flare]
[image: nodes for uber flare]