# How to create a flashing lens flare effect?

Tags: compositing-nodes

How can I create a flashing lens flare effect like the one [featured in the Studio Khara logo](https://youtu.be/j-lvFItSxz4?t=15s)?

It is visible during the entire 16th second of the video.

Comment: Animate the threshold value of the *Glare* Node or animate the factor a *Color Mix* node between the image with the glare and one without

Comment: Could something like that work with Fog Glow?

Comment: I suspect so, yes, most node values can be animated in pretty much the same way as anything else in Blender.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63464/how-to-make-a-circular-rainbow-effect You may mix this effect with the @Duarte Farrajota Ramos 's solutions mentioned above.